# Undefined (Opening, Encl, Subject) control sequence in template of scrartcl document

Tags: packages, letters, classicthesis, undefined, scrartcl

Hi I am using this overleaf template for a presentation letter based on the Classic thesis template by André Miede:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/carta-de-apresentacao-template/gpwkqmqwncsc

The letter works very well but some of the commands for the letter type seem to be undefined. This is how they look in the template:

```
\newcommand{\ToAddr}[1]{\noindent \\ #1\vspace{1em}}
\newcommand{\LetterDate}[1]{\hfill #1\par}
\newcommand{\Subject}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\justifying\textbf{Sub: #1}\par\vspace{0.5em}}
\newcommand{\Opening}[1]{\justifying #1\par\vspace{1em}}
\newcommand{\Sign}[1]{\vspace{2em}\noindent Sincerely yours,\vspace{1em}\\ #1\par}
%\newcommand{\Encl}[1]{\vspace{1em}\noindent\footnotesize\color{Maroon}\emph{Encl. #1}\\ #1\par}
```

Trying to use \Opening, \Subject and \Encl produces an undefined command error. This is the one for opening:

```
\Opening #1->\justifying 
                         #1\par \vspace {1em}
l.54 \Opening{Hi}
                 
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I think the issue is a missing package within the scrartcl document but I cannot find it.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: `ragged2e` package defines the command `\justifying` (although there are almost no cases it does anything useful as justified text is the default)

Comment: Off topic : Why use`scrartcl` class and not `scrlttr2` for a letter?

Comment: Ty very much @DavidCarlisle for the comment. That solved the issues for all the commands. Do you think you could post the comment as a reply and I can

Comment: @Jhor in another template based on the classic thesis with scrlttr2 I have had issues to make citations work. This one works good enough for me except for these three inbuilt commands. In any case, it may be my incompetence since I do not understand 80% of latex commands I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ragged2e` package defines the command `\justifying` (although there are almost no cases it does anything useful as justified text is the default).